# Filter question i R, remove duplicate values and only keep min value

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to use a database in R and need to add some filters.
On selected routes you have to change bus to get to your final destination. I have filtered on these routes, but I need to remove duplicate values and keep the one with minimum values. So I can see how many departures for the selected destination.

Current filter code:

```
filterroutes <- c("5", "10")
busroutes <- database %>% filter(Route %in% filterroutes)
```

Table after filter on routes 5 and 10

```
Route Time NDepartures
5      2   1
5      3   1
5      3   1
5      4   1
5      5   1
10     1   1
10     3   3
10     4   2
10     6   1
10     7   2
```

I want to keep routes with unique time stamp and if duplicate keep the one with minimum `NDepartures`.

Should Return

```
Route Time NDepartures
5      2   1
5      3   1
5      3   1
5      4   1
5      5   1
10     1   1
10     6   1
10     7   2
```

Someone told me I could use a `NDepartures == min(NDepartures)` but I could not get this to work.

Comment: I don't understand why you are retaining all rows for the 5 route, but removing two of the rows for the 10 route.  Can you explain this to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
busroutes %>% 
   group_by(Time) %>% 
   #n() equals # of obs in each group "Time"
   filter(n()==1 | (n()>1 & NDepartures==min(NDepartures))) %>%
   ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   Time [7]
  Route  Time NDepartures
  <int> <int>       <int>
1     5     2           1
2     5     3           1
3     5     3           1
4     5     4           1
5     5     5           1
6    10     1           1
7    10     6           1
8    10     7           2
```